How to solve $f\left(x\right)=f\left(0\right)-a\int_{0}^{x}\frac{du}{\left(b+\int_{0}^{u}f\left(w\right)dw\right)^{2}}\ $ for $f$
If some $a,b, f(0) \in \mathbb{C}$ are chosen, how does one solve the functional equation
$$f\left(x\right)=f\left(0\right)-a\int_{0}^{x}\frac{du}{\left(b+\int_{0}^{u}f\left(w\right)dw\right)^{2}}\ $$
?

I've gotten this far, but don't know how to proceed:
Let $f(0)=c$
Then using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus we can transform the original problem into the initial value problem:
$$f''(x)=\frac{2af\left(x\right)}{\left(b+\int_{0}^{x}f\left(t\right)dt\right)^{3}}, f(0)=c$$

Unfortunately, there might not be reading material to reference for this problem, because I came up with the problem myself while playing around with Newton's law of universal gravitation, and I'm not even sure that I was doing the physics correctly.

Do you mind providing some context about where this equation comes from?

@温泽海 I came up with the problem while I was attempting to use Newton's law of universal gravitation (where $f(x)$ has been substituted for the upward velocity $v(t)$) to solve for the precise kinematics (not treating $g$ as though it's constant) of an upward-thrown rigid body subject to the gravitational pull of the Earth. I'm not actually fully sure if I'm doing the physics correctly, but the idea is that some radius value for the Earth is $b$, $GM=a$, and $f(0)$ corresponds to the initial upward velocity at the moment of throwing the rigid body upward

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4776675/does-this-differential-equation-has-analytic-solution/4778494#4778494.

@Gonçalo is it possible to use Fabian's solution to this problem to roughly calculate how long it will take before an upward-launched rigid body begins to fall back down to Earth, given the initial upward velocity at the time of the launch? If so, would the estimate in most cases be much different in comparison to an estimate that treats the rate of deceleration due to gravity as though it's constant?

You are interested to solve the problem
$$
f\left(x\right)=c-a\int_{0}^{x}\frac{du}{\left(b+\int_{0}^{u}f\left(w\right)dw\right)^{2}} \tag{1}$$
for $a,b,c$ some constants. Let us first take the derivative of (1) and obtain the equivalent problem
$$ f'(x) = -  \frac{a}{\left(b+\int_{0}^{x}f\left(w\right)dw\right)^{2}}, \qquad f(0) = c\,. \tag{2}
$$
In order to transform it into a pure differential equation, we introduce the function $F(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f\left(w\right)dw$ with $F'(x) = f(x)$. The problem then reads
$$ F''(x) = -  \frac{a}{\left(b+F(x)\right)^{2}}, \quad F(0) = 0, \qquad F'(0)= c\,.\tag{3}$$
In order to solve this ODE, we try to find the function $w(F) = F'(x(F))$ (assuming that $F(x)$ is (locally) invertible such that $x(F)$ exists). This function fulfills the ODE
$$ w'(F) = \frac{F''}{F'} = - \frac{a}{w(b+F)^2}, \quad w(0) = c\,.
$$
This equation is separable with the solution ($c>0$)
$$ w(F) =  \sqrt{ c^2 - \frac{2 a F}{b(F+b)}} \tag{a}\,.
$$
As $w = F'$, we have another separable equation to obtain $F(x)$ (implicitly) via
$$ \int_0^{F(x)}\! \left(c^2 - \frac{2 a y}{b(y+b)}\right)^{-1/2}\,dy  =x \,. \tag{b}$$
This integral can be solved by elementary methods. The solution is (unfortunately) rather lengthy.
With this, we have (implicitly) solved for $f(x)$. Given a $x$, we solve for $F$ using (b). The value of $f(x)$ is then given by  $\sqrt{ c^2 - \frac{2 a F}{b(F+b)}}$ due to (a).
